# Azure Functions - What is the purpose of having host.json and local.settings.json

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I can see two json files(host.json and local.settings.json) has been added in Azure Function directory.

#### host.json

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### local.settings.json

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

What is the purpose of having these two json files?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is very clearly explained in the documentation , from the docs,

[**`host.json`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json)

> The host.json metadata file contains global configuration options that
> affect all functions for a function app. This article lists the
> settings that are available starting with version 2.x of the Azure
> Functions runtime.

[**`Local settings`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#local-settings-file)

> The local.settings.json file stores app settings, connection strings,
> and settings used by local development tools. Settings in the
> local.settings.json file are used only when you're running projects
> locally.

Comment: I wish it were consistent with AspNet:  appsettings.json for local and prod settings.  appsettings.{environment}.json for settings that override/add to appsettings.json.   Then when {environment} is development, you get the same effect as local.settings.json.

Comment: Does the Host.json settings get deployed to the Azure Function?

Comment: @Joe yes you are right

Comment: Documentation doesn't share a key detail... where in Azure Function is host.json deployed to/visible? Answer: follow these in the left-nav: YourFuncAppRoot\App files\host.json

Comment: @DonCheadle: I've been looking for that detail, about where the host.json is within a Function App.  It was very difficult to find anything about where it's deployed to.  Thanks.

Comment: My host.json wasn't deploying until I set the file to 'copy always' in properties.

Comment: To override a host.json setting in slot settings: `AzureFunctionsJobHost__`

Answer (score 8):

Host.json is to set configs once you deploy Azure function on Azure. You can relate it to app.config/web.config. for example, you may need to define a AzureWebStorage connection string for a Storage in Azure for fucntion to run. Any other appsetting must be defined here too.

Whereas local.settings.json defines local settings which you will use for your development. For example AzureWebstorage defined is pointing to local storage. This file will be ignored during deployment. This is akin to your dev config file.