# Does Azure Function log-level in host.json overwrite appsettings-file loglevel and Application insight loglevel?

Tags: .net, azure, logging, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

log level can be configured in host.json file:

- [Configuring Log Level for Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408032/configuring-log-level-for-azure-functions)
- [What is the default logLevel threshold in Azure Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64591543/what-is-the-default-loglevel-threshold-in-azure-functions)

In my app in addition to host.json i have appsettings for dev/test/prod.
The appsettingsfiles does not specify anything about loglevel, and nothing about application insight loglevel.

Does host.json impose its configured log-level to all environments, including application insight loggin?

Comment: Yes, `host.json` is used for logging data in application insights for azure functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does host.json impose its configured log-level to all environments, including application insight loggin?

- Yes, host.json configures application insights and logs function app logs to application insights.
- In **Host.json** we will set the logging configurations which are used after deploying the function app.

Example:

```
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
          "samplingSettings": {
            "isEnabled": true,
            "excludedTypes": "Request"     
          }
        }
        }
```

[image]

- **local.settings.json** contains `AzureWebJobsStorage`,    `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME`,`APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`

Example:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "27ef877b-5298-4cd9-8a45-a6b99bcc395d"
  }
}
```

[image]

**References taken from:**

- [Azure Functions - What is the purpose of having host.json and local.settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62669672/17623802)
- [Work with Azure Functions Core Tools | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#local-settings-file)
- [host.json reference for Azure Functions 2.x | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json)
- [c# - Application Insights not working in locally running Azure Worker Function - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74985290/application-insights-not-working-in-locally-running-azure-worker-function/75002081#75002081)